# Hide public classes in JAR

Tags: java, jar

Does anyone know the way to hide public classes in JAR file. In other words is there any way to create "jar-visible" classes. The point is to hide public classes in my JAR file and provide to my JAR-users access to specified classes. F.e. similar thing is implemented in OSGI framework with the help of "Export-Package" parameter in MANIFEST.MF

Comment: You already mentioned the solution - OSGi, which was designed to overcome just this sort of shortcoming in basic JARs.

Comment: in my opinion, in that scenario you're going to need to think again the architecture of your proyect.

Comment: The problem is that I am developing a separate module for Android which is a single JAR file. There is a set of packages and subpackages inside and in order to use  different application layers inside my JAR I need to use public classes and/or interfaces otherwise I should place all my java files into one single package and make them default visibility and expose only public classes. But this approach brakes all package structure! There must be some way to overcome that issue...

Comment: This can be done with ProGuard lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ProGuard ( http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ ) lib.