# Prevent projects from calling methods in distributable jar

Tags: java

I have created a JAR project which consists of two packages :

- package `a` : contains some methods
- package `b` : contains methods calling the ones of package `a`

Now I want that the projects using my JAR should not be able to call methods in package `a`, instead they must call methods defined in package `b`.

Comment: if a jar is on the classpath then (generally speaking) everything else on the classpath has access to its public classes and their public methods.

Comment: You can have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872124/how-to-hide-the-internal-structure-of-a-java-api-to-the-rest-of-the-world. What is your use case exactly ?

Comment: @Gaël: I created a jar with DAO layer and Service Layer. This jar is being used in other projects by different teams. I want to restrict other calling projects from directly accessing DAO layer, instead they should use the services exposed in Service Layer interface only.

Comment: @MohitGarg : at some point you have to assume people are using your API correctly. Just tell them they should only use Service Layer.

Answer (score 0):

Use default access modifier

If you don't use any modifier for a variable or method , it is treated as default  access modifier. The default modifier is accessible only within package.

Comment: In this case package `B` could not call package `A` methods, that's not what @Mohit wants.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is not posible in java with the current modifiers.

However I recommend you to do:

1. Define the methods in **package[A]** with **protected** modifier.
2. In **package[B]** create a **proxy class**. This class must **inherit** from its counterpart in **package[A]**. This class will encpsulate the methods of its similar class in **Packacge[A]** and will make the methods calls to the **package[A]** counterpart.
3. In **package[B]** you have to make the calls through **proxy class**.